# Add timestamp in excel worksheet if row has changed

Tags: excel, timestamp, vba

I need to add or update timestamp, to excel workbook, if row has been changed. I am doing data import, but I need to see which row was updated/added and on which date.

So far I have found and adjusted the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    With Target
        If .Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Not Intersect(Range("A2:BL9999"), .Cells) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            With .Cells(1, 65)
                 .NumberFormat = "yyyy.mm.dd"
                 .Value = Now
            End With
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The problem is, timestamp is always added relative to the row where the changes have been made + 65 rows, not in column BM (index 65).

Can you advise me, which function should I use or change?

Comment: change `With .Cells(1, 65)` to `With Cells(1, 65)`

Comment: in this case it is not updating at all

Comment: code updates `BM1` cell

Comment: maybe I am doing something wrong, but no changes occur, I even tried to copy in new excel file and set the range and cells to 10, if these changes are made, there are no updates in worksheet at all

Comment: works for me as expected. Cell `BM1` contains timestamp. Btw, code works only if changed _single_ cell in range `A2:BL9999`

Comment: started from zero and worked, but row has to be dynamic, only column constant (for each row)

Comment: use `With Cells(.Row, "BM")`

Comment: Since Target can be a multi-cell range, you need to process each row in that range.  Right now, if someone updates ten rows you will only register one of those rows. Also, you should create a new range from your Intersect check, and only operate on that range.

Answer (score 2):

As well as the fix for column `BM` better to

1. process all the rows that may have changed rather than exit withput any record
2. turn-off `ScreenUpdating` for speed

*code*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

Set rng1 = Intersect(Target, Range("A2:BL9999"))
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

For Each rng2 In rng1.Cells
    With Cells(rng2.Row, 65)
          .NumberFormat = "yyyy.mm.dd"
           .Value = Now
    End With
Next

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To change your reference relative to the entire row, use `.EntireRow`.

So that line should read: `With .EntireRow.Cells(1, 65)`

Note that you can still use A1 style references even when working with a single row.  This can keep you from having to count columns.  For instance, and in this case, `.EntireRow.Range("BM1")` means the exact same thing as `.EntireRow.Cells(1, 65)`.